# Add Reference dialog not working after installing VS2012 update 1

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I installed Visual Studio 2012 Update 1 and now  I can't add a reference to any project.

The Add Reference dialog does not open at all.

The ActivityLog.xml contains these errors :

```
550  Begin package load [ReferenceManagerPackage] {48D4A2C1-02AD-4F18-9153-620511BACB7B}  VisualStudio 2012/12/09 00:39:58.544 
551 ERROR CreateInstance failed for package [ReferenceManagerPackage] {48D4A2C1-02AD-4F18-9153-620511BACB7B} 80131522 VisualStudio 2012/12/09 00:39:58.575 
552 ERROR End package load [ReferenceManagerPackage] {48D4A2C1-02AD-4F18-9153-620511BACB7B} 80004005 - E_FAIL VisualStudio 2012/12/09 00:39:58.575
```

I'm on VS2012 Professional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following a [suggestion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/7750703d-c7b8-4cd8-bc5a-f0ba3ac27b40) from the Visual Studio Setup and Installation forums, I uninstalled and reinstalled Visual Studio and the problem is gone for now ...

Note that I had difficulties uninstalling Visual Studio, I guess the install had been corrupted but by what ?